# Project Zomboid Dedicated Server on GOG

Tags: gog, project-zomboid

I'm trying to create a dedicated server to play with my friends, but all the guides I find start with "Go to Steam and...", but I bought the game on GOG.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not familiar with the game, but I found [this thread on GOG](https://www.gog.com/forum/project_zomboid/multiplayer_private_server). Sometimes the server files are free on Steam and do not require the game.